# Apache Spark : spark.eventLog.dir on Windows Environment

Tags: java, windows, apache-spark, event-log

I am working on Spark 1.4 on windows environment.  I have to set eventLog directory so that I can reopen the Spark UI after application has finished.

But I am not able to set eventLog.dir, It gives error on Windows environment.

Configuation is :

```
<entry key="spark.eventLog.enabled" value="true" />
<entry key="spark.eventLog.dir" value="file:///c:/sparklogs" />
```

Exception I get :

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cygpath": CreateProcess error=2,  
The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:206)
```

Can anybody give any advice on it?

Comment: It doesn't give any error on Linux/Unix environment. On Linux, I am giving                                           
    `<entry key="spark.eventLog.dir" value="home/user/sparkLogs" />`
and its working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success with this format:

```
entry key="spark.eventLog.dir" value="c:////sparklogs" />
```

Comment: No success. Still stuck with it.